# Updating all objects in array with UseState in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm starting with this:

```
const [notificationList, setNotificationList] = useState([]);
```

The array is then populated. Afterwards I want to update every single object in that array... but not working.

```
setNotificationList(notificationList.map(notif => { ...notif, isRead: true }))
```

I think it's obvious but I need to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error. If you run the code, you should see it in the console.

```
// this is the usual "old" syntax
function() {
  return true
}
// this is the es6 arrow function
() => {
  return true
}
// this is the es6 arrow function without braces
() => true
```

As you can see here, you can omit `{}` in an arrow function. However, if you want to return an object, you have to be explicit otherwise the engine doesn't understand_

```
// not what you want
() => { key: 'value' }
// what you want
() => ({ key: 'value' })
```

solution:

```
setNotificationList(notificationList.map(notif => ({ ...notif, isRead: true })))
```